# How to represent data in the cross product of categories in R

Tags: r, dataframe, table-relationships

I have a data frame. In that data frame I have two categorical variables. If I consider the cross product of those 2, then I have one row per element in my data frame.

The table shown below is a table of frequencies. Instead of showing the number of occurrences I would like to show the column test. Any ideas on how to do this? I have been trying to figure it out but I am not finding a way.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it seems like you want to [pivot the data from long form to wide form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/8366499). You can do this pretty easily with dplyr and the `pivot_wider` function:

First we'll make some sample data (in the future, instead of including your data as an image, use the `dput` function to output it in format we can copy and paste to reproduce the problem):

```
df = data.frame(data_set=c('a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'),
                category=rep.int(c('d','e','f'),3),
                tests=abs(rnorm(9,sd=3)),
                best_threads=rnorm(9, 50, 20))
  data_set category     tests best_threads
1        a        d 3.1162129     15.61119
2        a        e 4.0933109     19.71428
3        a        f 0.1026443     44.63157
4        b        d 3.3482561     47.68211
5        b        e 5.9149545     69.19018
6        b        f 4.2248788     52.54404
7        c        d 3.4384232     41.86539
8        c        e 4.2985273     76.49010
9        c        f 0.2164352     44.36635
```

Then we just pivot it to wide form, using `data_set` to be the new column names and `tests` as the value of those cells. We need to drop `best_threads`, either in the pivot_wider function, or beforehand:

```
library(dplyr)
pivot_wider(df,                        # Data frame to pivot
            -best_threads,             # Drop the best_threads variable 
            names_from = 'data_set',   # The variable to use for column names
            values_from = 'tests'      # The variable to put in the cells
    )

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  category     a     b     c
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 d        3.12   3.35 3.44 
2 e        4.09   5.91 4.30 
3 f        0.103  4.22 0.216
```